# Footer is hiding content

Tags: css, joomla, footer

I've to change something in this page : http://www.christinat-vin.ch/commande

I added a "zip code" line and a "phone number" line, but now, the footer is hidding the body content, and it's impossible to send the form.

I saw in another topic that changing the footer css may be the solution. So I edited the .footer in the css file through my FTP, but the change is not taking effect on the webiste, despite the hard refresh. I'm the admin, so I don't think there is any permissions that I need to do that.

The original .footer is :

```
pied {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#333;
position:abspolute;
display:float;
float:left;
width:700px;
margin-top:100px;
margin-left:-50px;
z-index:3;
font-size:10px;
background-color:#d6d6d6;
padding:1px;
padding-left:50px;
margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

And the changed one is :

```
pied {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#333;
position:inline-block;
display:static;
float:left;
width:700px;
margin-top:100px;
margin-left:-50px;
z-index:3;
font-size:10px;
background-color:#d6d6d6;
padding:1px;
padding-left:50px;
margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

Do you have any ideas to fix this ? Thanks !

Comment: My "hi everyone" in the beginning is not displayed, i don't know why...

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you can undo your changes in your css, the footer isn't the problem.
CodeGator is right, if you edit your `template.css` and write:

```
.wrapper {

    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    height: 157vh; 
}
```

It should works fine. But I don't know how to fix it right with Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using an Iframe on that page, as you can not give auto height to Iframe, you must increase height of Iframe or remove the use of Iframe.

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution ! But it works only when I tried with the inspector. The change doesn't take effect when I edit the .wrapper in the .css file :(